# DT::datatables() generated html table shows display anomalies (missing characters) when column level search is used

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, dt, knitr-spin

I am trying to put interactive, sortable tables in html summaries produced by using rmarkdown::render from an R script. For producing tables I am using datatables() from DT package. Reports are generated fine and tables look pretty good, until you do a column level filter/search, after which display shows some funny problems. My question will become clearer with the following example.

```
#' ---
#' title: "Test"
#' author: test
#' output: 
#'   html_document:
#'     toc: true
#' ---

#' <style type="text/css">
#'   .main-container {
#'     max-width: 1200px;
#'     margin-left: auto;
#'     margin-right: auto;
#'   }
#' </style>

#' ### Test data

#+ setup, include=FALSE, echo=TRUE
require(dplyr)
require(DT)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

#+ core_code, include=FALSE, echo=TRUE 
plants <- read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/cluster/plantTraits.csv")
plants<- plants %>% 
  mutate( ID = paste0("ID_" , sprintf("%04d", 1:136)  )  ) %>%
  select(ID, X:unsp)

#+ test_table, echo = FALSE
datatable( plants ,
           extensions = c("Buttons" , "FixedColumns"),
           filter = 'top',
           options = list( autoWidth = TRUE , 
                           dom = 'Blftip',
                           pageLength = 100,
                           searchHighlight = TRUE,
                           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'print'),
                           scrollX = TRUE,
                           fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2)),
           class = c('compact cell-border stripe hover') ,
           rownames = FALSE)
```

Produces the table (screenshot):
[image]

If I do a search for 048 in the ID column, it shows the right row, like this...
[image]

But then, if I cancel the filter, and bring all the rows back, rows have characters missing from ID column. 
[image]

This would happen to any column that I search, or any other data. It does not happen if I use the main search box (at right side top corner). I am running RStudio(Version 1.1.463) on Mac(OS X 10.11.6) but I have tested the produced html file on Chrome, Safari, and RStudio inbuilt browser on Mac; and Chrome and IE on Win7. Any clues about how to address this?

Comment: check if `ID_0001` is listed in ulterior rows? you may have new row order after filtering.

Comment: There is only one row with ID_0001, the one with X == Aceca. The problem is that after filtering is removed, leading zeros in ID are gone, and in row number 4 in the screenshot ID is now showing as ID_0 where it should be ID_0004.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a solution, but more of circumventing the problem. Since there were no suggestions, I starting disabling all the options I was using and it turns out that it was the highlight search results that was causing the issue. So if I do:

```
#+ test_table, echo = FALSE
datatable( plants ,
           extensions = c("Buttons" , "FixedColumns"),
           filter = 'top',
           options = list( autoWidth = TRUE , 
                           dom = 'Blftip',
                           pageLength = 100,
                           searchHighlight = FALSE,
                           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'print'),
                           scrollX = TRUE,
                           fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2)),
           class = c('compact cell-border stripe hover') ,
           rownames = FALSE)
```

It works fine now.